# CKEditor appears gray in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, ckfinder

I visited a lot of websites to find a solution.

My editor works in almost every browser except internet explorer.
In internet explorer the space(textarea) to change the content isnt showing up, the rest of the editor is visible. Does anyone knows a solution? I didn't find it on the internet.

Updating the editor maybe is a solution, but it took me a while to configure it together with ckfinder, so I'm afraid that it ckfinder isn't working after an update.

The editor worked a few months ago, but I didn't work on the website for a few months.

```
<textarea id="textarea" name='text' class='editor'></textarea>
```

To show my editor.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
             $('textarea.editor').ckeditor( 
             function() { 
                 /* callback code */ 
                  }, 
                {   

                   language : 'nl',
                   uiColor : '#e9eaee',
                   toolbarStartupExpanded : false,
                      toolbar :
                            [
                                    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', 'Source'] },{ name: 'document', items : ['DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
                         { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
                              { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
                            '/',
                            { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
                              { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
                            { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
                         '/',
                            { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
                            { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
                           { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar' ] }
                            ],
                      height: '225',
                      extraPlugins : 'tableresize'

                } );
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your add-ons, and if the problem was solved, enable add-ons one by one to find the one which cause the problem.

Comment: Do hou mean the extra plugins like tableresizer?

Comment: IE Add-ons ,and yes next step plugins like tableresizer

Comment: I tried to disable these, for ie 7, 8 it does work but for ie9 and ie10 it doesn't. Please let someone destroy internet explorer.

Comment: Actually , it is difficult to find problem in such these cases. One soultion is, changeing Ckeditor with another editor like Tinymce.
Also try to increase or decrease jquery version you are using

Comment: I will take a look at that tomorrow don't have much time right now, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments on the previous answer, the problem is with IE10, right? Sounds like a version issue. IE10 is not supported for CKFinder 2.2.2, so you could try updating CKF.

It would help if you include the CKFinder, CKEditor and Browser versions in the question :).

It could be a config or general JS issue too - do you have a JSfiddle or other link we could check out? Also, have you checked what the Developer tools for IE10 reports, there could very well be informative errors there.